Software Updater is broken ("Failed to download repository information")

When I run the software updater, all I get is this. How can I fix this or even determine what's actually wrong? There don't seem to be any logs, I even tried looking through the source code but I couldn't figure out what it's actually trying to do under the hood.
Ubuntu 22.04

Running apt update just yields a few unrelated warnings about a Steam PPA:
Err:7 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Start by running sudo apt update on the command line, show us what the output is in an Edit.

@ThomasWard Sure

The warnings are not unrelated. It seems that the server at repo.steampowered.com was offline at that time. You can see that apt failed to download https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/stable/InRelease. However, I have just successfully downloaded that file. So maybe try again?
